# Auto-mount nfs volume on startup fails with "killed by TERM signal"

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm trying without success to auto-mount on startup a nfs partition to /build folder.

I do have nfs-common installed, and actually it works when I use mount -a.
Furthermore this used to work on my xubuntu 13.*, after upgrading to 14.10 it stopped working.

The build folder is owned by regular user and is world-writable. My fstab entry looks like this:
some_intranet_host.com:/build /build     nfs

dmesg displays this error:
init: idmapd-mounting (/build) main process (304) killed by TERM signal

I already tried some suggestions like adding uid=1000,gid=1000 etc but nothing seems to work.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you restarted the nfs services and proceed troubleshooting. Also try upgrading the `nfs-common`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading ubuntu gnome from 14.04 to 14.10. The following solved it:

Edit `/etc/default/nfs-common` and make sure it says:

```
NEED_STATD=yes
```

Restart and your nfs mounts should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this without success. I'll investigate later, maybe my problem is completely different than yours was.